# Performance Issue with ListControl and Observable Dictionary WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

I have an itemsControl bound to an observable dictionary, showing both the Key and Value in two textboxes, 
It takes about 15 seconds for the usercontrol to load. 
I tried virtualizing stackpanels and switching it to either a listbox or using a regular dictionary, and the lag still occurs

Any ideas what might be causing this, and how I can get it to load faster?

```
 public partial class WordsView : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public WordsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Dictionarylist.ItemsSource = curDic;
        }

        private ObservableDictionary<string,int> cur_dic = new ObservableDictionary<string, int>(App.PredDic);
        public ObservableDictionary<string, int> curDic
        {
            get { return cur_dic; }
            set
            {
                SetField(ref cur_dic, value, "curDic");

            }
        }
}
}
```

and my xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ez.Management.WordsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ez.Management"
              DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
              xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:Ez.Properties" 
             xmlns:main ="clr-namespace:Ez"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
       <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Words">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="Dictionarylist" ItemsSource="{Binding curDic}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel></VirtualizingStackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="3">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Grid.Column="0" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>


                    </ItemsControl>

                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` is taking time... Try setting it to `False`. Like,

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```

Comment: That did not seem to help